# Number of recursive permutation for $1,...,N$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, recurrence-relations

Calculate in recursion the number of permutations of the numbers $1,\dots, N$ in which each number is greater than all those to its left or smaller than all those to its left.

I tried to look at the base cases, and I got this recursion:
$p(n)= n\cdot p(n-1)$
but I think it doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: Why not look at examples?  how many are there for $N=2$?  $N=3$?

Answer (score 0):

Given that there is one such permutation for $N=1$, your recursion would give $N!$ permutations satisfying the condition, that is all permutations, so is clearly not correct.

Hint: work right to left. What are the possible values of the rightmost element of the permutation? Note that once this element is removed, you are left with a permutation of the remaining $N-1$ elements satisfying the same condition.

Comment: I noticed that the rightmost element should be 1 or N but still, I can't figure it out. please help